# Как обойти все файлы в папке и подпапках и добавить в каждый файл массив?

Tags: java, файлы

```
                Корневая Папка
            /         |         \
      Папка А       Папка Б     Папка В 
    /    |    \     / | \      /    |    \ 
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  . . .  n-2.txt  n-1.txt  n.txt
```

Писать собираюсь на java!

```
public static void processFilesFromFolder (File folder)
    {

        File[] folderEntries = folder.listFiles();

        for (File entry : folderEntries)
        {

            if (entry.isDirectory())
            {

                processFilesFromFolder(entry);

                continue;
            }

            // Как извлечь путь папки/файла, который находится в папке folder?

            AppendToFile (folder);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Делаете рекурсивную функцию которая в один общий массив добавляет файлы, а для вложенных папок вызывает себя же, для обработки этой папки

Comment: Лучше все-таки не рекурсивно, а добавлять в какую-нибудь структуру, список папок, которые еще нужно обойти. На чем писать то собираетесь?

Comment: А о каком языке программирования идет речь? Или вы хотите получить алгоритм обхода дерева?

Comment: Писать собираюсь на java.

Comment: а зачем использовать массив? можно его заменить листом файлов? 
`List<File>` ? Или это принципиально? Если можно я внизу постарался реализовать этот метод и проверил его. Он рабочий.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Алгоритм, который обходит все папки начиная с корневой:

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
void print(File file, int depth){
  printName(file.name(), depth);
  depth++;
  if (file.isDir()){
   for (File nested : file:list()){
   files.add(nested);
   print(nested, depth);
   }
}
```

Где параметр File это корневой каталог.